# Passing objectId from viewDidLoad to another function using Parse method getObjectInBackgroundWithId not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm a beginner working with Parse and Swift. I need to update the object referred to in my viewDidLoad in another function within the same controller. How do I pass the currently loaded object's objectId without having to hardcode it like this:

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("8DkYgraEJq")
```

Here is my viewDidLoad function:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       var query = PFQuery(className: "CheckedBaggage")
       query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
       query.whereKey("respondedTo", notEqualTo: true)
       query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
         (CheckedBaggage: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
           if error != nil {
            println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
          } else {
            // The find succeeded.

            self.randomBaggageLabel.text = CheckedBaggage.objectForKey("message") as? NSString
            CheckedBaggage.save()

            println(CheckedBaggage.objectId)

            let baggageId = CheckedBaggage.objectId

            println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
        }
    }
```

I would like to try and pass the variable baggageId, which should be the object's ID as a string, as an argument to the getObjectInBackgroundWithId block in my carryIt function:

```
    @IBAction func carryIt(sender: AnyObject!) {
       println("CarryIt is being called")
       var query = PFQuery(className: "CheckedBaggage")
       query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(baggageId) {
         (CheckedBaggage: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          if error != nil {
            println(error)
          } else if let CheckedBaggage = CheckedBaggage {
            println("object hello!")
            CheckedBaggage["respondedTo"] = true
            CheckedBaggage["response"] = self.kindnessMessage.text
            CheckedBaggage.save()
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an "unresolved identifier" error. It updates my Parse database perfectly fine if I hardcode the object ID, but I can't do it this way. Here's a screenshot of the error:[image: Parse error]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: declare baggageId at class level. it will not be accessible outside the function.

Comment: Glad it was such a simple fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize baggageId. To use it in multiple functions, it must be scoped at class level as the comment said. To set it after it has been declared, it must be a "var", not a constant "let".

```
var baggageId = ""
func viewDidload() {
    var query = ...
    query.get... {
       baggageId = CheckedBaggege.objectId
    }

}

func shipIt() {
    var query = ...
    query.getObjectWithId(baggageId) ...
}
```